# The Formula For Entanglement Entropy of an Evaporating Black Hole

Tags: black-holes, quantum-information, entropy, quantum-entanglement, hawking-radiation

I am trying to find a proof for the formula for entanglement entropy of an evaporating Black Hole. It is introduced and used in many papers such as **The entropy of Hawking radiation**, by Ahmed Almheiri, Thomas Hartman, Juan Maldacena, Edgar Shaghoulian and Amirhossein Tajdini, *REVIEWS OF MODERN PHYSICS, VOLUME 93, JULY–SEPTEMBER 2021*.
https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.93.035002 https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.06872

\begin{equation}
S=\min _X\left\{\operatorname{ext}_X\left[\frac{\operatorname{Area}(X)}{4 G_N}+S_{\text {semi-cl }}\left(\Sigma_X\right)\right]\right\}
\end{equation}

Is there any proof for it? Please guide me about it.